# \overbrace and \underbrace with square bracket

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I'm trying to put a nice square bracket over a complex text, it should look like an `\overline` but with ending like 
`\ulcorner` and `\urcorner`.
The presence of `\overrightarrow` and `\overleftarrow` makes me believe that is possible to decorate the end of the `\overline` bar.

I know the existence of `\overbrace`, but I need a square bracket; moreover, `\overbrace` takes too much vertical space

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try [`\mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)'s `\underbracket` and `\overbracket`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
\[
  \overbrace{a+b+c}^{d} \quad \overbracket{a+b+c}^{d} \quad
  \underbrace{a+b+c}_{d} \quad \underbracket{a+b+c}_{d}
\]
\end{document}
```

You can adjust the rule width and bracket height/depth via optional arguments. From the [`mathtools` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf) (section **3.3.2 Braces and brackets**, p. 14):

```
\underbracket[<rule thickness>][<bracket height>]{<arg>}
\overbracket[<rule thickness>][<bracket height>]{<arg>}
```

---

Or, a more subtle approach with [`abraces`](http://ctan.org/pkg/abraces):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abraces}% http://ctan.org/pkg/abraces
\begin{document}
\[
  \overbrace{a+b+c}^{d} \quad \aoverbrace[L1R]{a+b+c}^{d} \quad
  \underbrace{a+b+c}_{d} \quad \aunderbrace[l1r]{a+b+c}_{d}
\]
\end{document}
```

The usage requires a brace specification `<spec>` as an optional argument to `\aoverbrace` and `\aunderbrace` (see the [`abraces` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/abraces/abraces-doc.pdf)):

[image]

Comment: I've rolled back an edit here as it pointed to a specific CTAN node rather than the mirror. Things might not work _today_ as there is some maintenance ongoing at DANTE.

Answer (score 9):

The "standard LaTeX" underbraces and overbraces quickly become straight lines with only minor bumps as soon as the material being embraced (pun intended) is of more than minimal length. To add some visual interest and pizzazz, one may want to consider using the `\undercbrace` and `\overcbrace` macros of the [MathTime Professional 2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package. Note that the full mtpro2 package isn't free of charge; however, its "lite" subset, which is all that's required to generate the curly braces shown below, is indeed available free of charge.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}%
\begin{document}
Curly over- and underbraces of the \texttt{mtpro2} package:
\[
   \overcbrace{a+b+c+d+e+f}^{ghi} \quad 
  \undercbrace{a+b+c+d+e+f}_{ghi}
\]

``Standard \LaTeX'' over- and underbraces:
\[
   \overbrace{a+b+c+d+e+f}^{ghi} \quad 
  \underbrace{a+b+c+d+e+f}_{ghi}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

When Unicode math font is loaded then `\overbracket` and `\underbracket` are standard horizontally scalable math objects. For example in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lmfonts]

$\overbracket{a+b+c}$

\bye
```