# Summing a list and specifying number of elements on list

Tags: math-mode, formatting

How would I create something like either of the following on LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132526/overbrace-with-square-bracket

Comment: `\overbrace{1 + 1 + \dots + 1}^n` and `\underbrace{1 + 1 + \dots + 1}_n`, respectively.