# How to add an underbrace and overbrace to a term in a equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I saw question about terms being partially ovarlapped in an equation but I don't want them to be partially overlapped, I just want one particular term to have have an underbrace and overbrace. I am new to LaTeX so I just want some simple line that I can copy and paste.

Comment: So you haven't even tried `\underbrace{\overbrace{x+y}^{over}}_{under}`?

Comment: Relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132526/overbrace-with-square-bracket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\underbrace{\overbrace{a+b+c}^{\mathrm{over}}}_{\mathrm{under}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. What does that mathrm do? Can it be applied in any other situation?

Comment: @David really _any_ latex tutorial will show `\mathrm` it's best to start with some basic tutorials rather than just copy answers all the time otherwise you'll be asking hundreds of questions, but `\mathrm`  makes text in a roman font designed for words. Never set words in the default math italic font as it is designed to make adjacent letters look like a product of variables.

Comment: @David: I suggest that you have a look at the `\text` command as well: see section 6 of the _User’s Guide for the `amsmath` Package_ (type `texdoc amsmath` on the command line to show it).  `\mathrm` and `\text` are somewhat intercheangeable in their functionality, but differ in some important details.  Basically, I’d recommend using `\mathrm` for words, or word chunks, that should look the same in all contexts, like “sin”, and `\text` for words, or phrases, that, contrarily, should change their font to match the font of the surrounding text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any idea how to avoid unequal length braces when the length of term in `overbrace` is  a lot larger than the length of the term in `underbrace`?

Comment: @adosar I can not guess what you mean, you probably should ask a new question with an example over/under brace is as wide as the term so by design they will have different lengths if the terms have different lengths

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For example, in this example `\underbrace{\overbrace{a+b+c}^{\mathrm{overflow+underflow}}}_{\mathrm{under}}` braces are of unequal length.

Comment: @adosar please don't ask new questions as comments on old answers, the site doesn't support code in this way, ask a new question with a real  test document