# overset/underset "sideways" and wide [ and ]

Tags: delimiters, overset

The usual `$\left[ abcd... \right]$`, places `[]` delimiters left-and-right, and spans the expression's height.

Contrariwise, I want to more-or-less `$\underset{]}{\overset{[}{ abcd... }}$`, placing `[]` "delimiters" top-and-bottom. Moreover (obviously), I want the `[]` sideways/horizontal, so to speak. And then I also want them wide, spanning the width of that `abcd...` expression.

Any way to do that, the more straightforward the better (i.e., optimally just some LaTeX directives without special packages, etc)? Thanks.

Comment: This should help, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132527/14103

Comment: Thanks, @Masroor That not only helps, it pretty much answers the question (cut-and-paste as an answer for a "check"). I cut-and-pasted the example in that post to test it out, and it works fine on my texlive-2014. (And, oops, that post illustrates I could have used overbrace/underbrace in my question as much better examples of what I wanted.)

Comment: Then we should close the current question and point to that one.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, it looks 100% duplicate to me, too.  But I didn't notice that other question (nor anything seemingly relevant) among the suggested answers while typing this question. Feel free to close/delete/whatever-you-like this question. And thanks again at-Masroor for the answer (duplicate or not:).