# Add annotation text below a matrix

Tags: matrices, annotations

I already have this matrix:

```
\[
    \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{array}
    \right]
\]
```

But I would like to annotate it, i.e. add some description below it (everything in red).. How can I do that please?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the `\underbracket` command from `mathtools`. I simplified your code using the `bmatrix` environment from `amsmath` (which is loaded by mathtools):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 

\begin{document}

\[
    \underbracket[0.6pt]{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \
    \end{bmatrix}}_\text{some text here}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`mathtools` has `\underbracket` (see here: [\overbrace and \underbrace with square bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132526/overbrace-and-underbrace-with-square-bracket)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
    \textcolor{red}{\underbracket{\textcolor{black}{\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{array}
    \right]}}_{\text{some text here}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if anyone knows how to do the block brackets..

Comment: @ojenn See my renewed answer